# Angular 2 final - testing service using setInterval, using fakeAsync and tick

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I have a service which internally uses `setInterval`. I would like to test that service. I'm trying to use `fakeAsync` and tick functions. Unfortunately I having some issues with using `fakeAsync` anywhere out of `it()` block.

Is it possible to set interval in `beforeEach` (or `beforeAll`) block and keep running inside zone?

Here is plunk of what I tried:
https://plnkr.co/edit/ZkscClm39eOdStrKtAox?p=preview

Comment: Did you find a solution to this question? 
Is this issue here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10127 related to it?

Comment: I created SchedulerService which basically wraps setTimeout and setInterval calls. And in tests I can simply mock it.